# Nsight Eclipse Edition not finding nvcc

Tags: eclipse, cuda, nvcc, nsight

I just installed CUDA 5.0 Preview (Mac OS X Lion) and I'm having trouble with Nsight.

The toolkit seems to be installed correctly. (Driver loads, nvcc -V works in bash, samples work fine).

When I create a new project I get warnings:

- Error launching external scanner info generator (nvcc -dryrun ...)
- Program 'nvcc' is not found in $PATH

In Preferences -> CUDA Toolkit I get no CUDA-compatible devices detected. Which is strange because I have nVidia GT 650M on my machine. So why doesn't Nsight recognize it?

If I try to build a project I get 2 errors:

- /bin/sh: nvcc: command not found
- make: *** [src/test.o] Error 127

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How do you start Nsight? Do you use /usr/local/cuda/bin/nsight? Unfortunately, it is not currently possible to launch Nsight by double-clinking the application on Mac OS X.

In the CUDA 5.0 Preview build we had a bug when shell script did not properly setup paths. This is how this script looks like in latest internal toolkit builds (you may need to adjust paths depending on your toolkit install location - in the final release installer will handle it):

```
#!/bin/sh
PATH="$PATH:/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-5.0/bin" DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-5.0/lib" "/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-5.0/libnsight/nsight.app/Contents/MacOS/nsight" $@
```

Comment: Starting Nsight from terminal solves most problems. I still get 2 warnings: invalid project path: Include Pat not found (Library/Frameworks (framework directory))

Comment: Aaargh. Thanks for bringing this up - I will look into it but it is likely an Apple bug introduced in 10.8 (nsight obtains that path from compiler). I will try to get it fixed for 5.0, you can safely ignore it meanwhile, it is totally harmless (it will not break anything, it is mostly for the users to detect typos in the project include paths)

Comment: The problem with include path warnings will be resolved in the upcoming CUDA Toolkit 5.0 release. Please ignore these messages in the mean time.

Comment: I'm working on 10.7.4, not 10.8. Everything seems to be working fine now, thanks. Do you have an ETA for the official CUDA 5.0?

Comment: I do not have a date for the next CUDA Toolkit release. Right, now I see - you are on 10.7, I've mistaken it with another Mac OS X issue reported on this site. The fix implemented will cover any OS where compiler returns invalid include paths so 10.7.4 will not show those warning as well.

Comment: Thanks, it worked on a 10.7.3. The only problem remains the missing driver on the old developer website.